# How can I set this WiFi network up, sharing internet through a Time Capsule?

Tags: wireless-networking, time-capsule, internet-sharing, billion

How would I go about setting this up?

[image]

So far I have the modem and the Billion talking to each other. The internet (vsat modem) ethernet cable goes to the 'ewan' port on the Billion and is setup as NAT enabled and IP address and DNS automatically obtained.

I want the Time Capsule to connect to the Billion wirelessly and to share the internet connection to the other wired and wirelessly connected devices.

In the picture, a solid line is *wired* and dotted line is *wireless*.

Comment: I have attempted a similar setup before and it didn't quite work. You can set the TC to extend a wireless network, but it seems this is only compatible with Apple Airports/Time Capsules.

Answer (score 1):

In order for that type of set-up to work you need wireless routers that support AP to AP wifi sharing, which is usually only limited to like AP devices.

Your only real current option with less headaches and better connect speeds is to have a wired connection from your Time Capsule to the Billion device.

Comment: Thank you, after some more research of my own I came to that same conclusion.. looks like I will have to lay out some cable. Once its wired what would be the setup?

Comment: @Vash no problem, and good luck

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact setup and it works fine. I improved it further by using the Timecapsule as the main router, removing the 7800N completely. Just configure the 'Internet' preferences of the TimeCapsule (I used Airport Utility on my Mac) to PPPoE, add you ISP username/pass and then apply. works brilliantly. Very fast.